# ¿como cerrar sesión Team Fundation Server en Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013, vb6

como cerrar sesión, o tambien cambiar de usuario??
en Team Fundation Server de Visual Studio..

[image: Mira la imagen]

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Lamentablemente me parece que TFS utiliza el usuario con el que has arrancado el visual studio. Si quieres entrar como otro usuario, prueba a ejecutar Visual Studio con ese usuario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quitar la credencial de tu usuario en windows, regresar a visual e iniciar sesión otra vez

[image: Esta Es la solución]